# Search on specific IDs in Solr

Tags: sql, solr, bigdata

Lets say I have big Solr that holds ~150M documents.
I also have 100,000 users that each user have documents that he saved. 
My questions:

1. What is the best way to store those documents IDs (the documents that each user saved)
2. If I decided to store the IDs in Mongo or MySql, what is the best way to allow the users to preform searches on their documents, meaning that I store only the Ids on Mongo/MySQL but the actual information is on Solr.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field username_s to each document that is being indexed. This field contains the username who may access the document. You can also use an array of users, if you would like to give more people access to this document.

Then in your backend you can add &fq=username_s:User. Even if there are 100 Million documents indexed, only those are shown who belong to the user.

```
/core/select?q=*.*&fq=username_s:<User>
```

You could store all documents for all users in the same core, leave the field "id" blank and an unqiue id is automatically generated for you by solr.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't think this solution will work in high scale, each document can be accessed by 1000s of users, how can I store in username_s so many user_ids?

Comment: Why would you want to store so many usernames in this field? If you want everyone to have access to this document then leave out the &fq=username_s parameter, or for certain users you can define a groups field. To log the IDs from the documents, which has been added by the user - this needs to be done in your own indexing pipeline script. Each document has it's own ID. You can log the document's ID into a MySQL-Database and show it up to the user who created it, for example in a web interface.